# Add filter to all query entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want add CompanyID filter to my all entity framework request.Because each user must see just their records.I dont want add filter (x=>x.CompanyID == cID) all methods in business layer.How can i add automaticly filter to requests.

My GetList method in DAL

```
     public List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {

            return filter == null
                ? context.Set<TEntity>().ToList()
                : context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Business

```
   public List<FinanceData> GetAll()
        {
            return _financeDal.GetList(filter:x=>x.CompanyID==_cID);
        }
```

Comment: Is it `ASP.NET` or not?

Comment: Are you using repository pattern?

Comment: yes and entity framework Code first

Comment: public class CustomdbContext : DbContext
{       
    public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyCustomerFilter<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query) where TEntity : Customer 
    {
         return query.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerctxId);
    }
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `IHasCompanyId` interface in such entities. And then implement repository pattern as:

```
public class MyRepository<T>
{
    public MyRepository(DbContext dbContext, int companyID)
    {
        if (dbContext == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Null DbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();

        CompanyID = companyID;
    }

    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected int CompanyID  { get; set; }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    // Add filter here
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        if(typeof(IHasCompanyID).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            return DbSet.Where(x => x.CompanyID == CompanyID);
        else 
            return DbSet;
    }
}
```

And initialize `_financeDal` as:

```
var _financeDal = new MyRepository<TEntity>(dbContext, companyID);
```

Comment: may be missing something like `where T : IHasCompanyId`

Comment: @tschmit007 Thanks for comment. I have chekec if entity implements this interface or not.

Comment: if (T is IHasCompanyId) not working -  i use this if (typeof(IHasCompanyID).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))

Comment: @user1924375 Thanks, I have typed it from mobile and didn't paid an attention. Updated.

Answer (score 24):

In the **Entity Framework Core 2.0**, you can use [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

1. Add filter just to the one entity:

   ```
   public interface IDelete
   {
       bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
   }

   public class Blog : IDelete
   {        
       public int BlogId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Url { get; set; }

       public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
   }

   public class Post : IDelete
   {
       public int PostId { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

       public int BlogId { get; set; }
       public Blog Blog { get; set; }
   }

   // Default method inside the DbContext or your default Context
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {         
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);  

       modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                   // Add Global filter to the Blog entity
                   .HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsDeleted == false);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                   // Add Global filter to the Post entity
                   .HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsDeleted == false);
   }
   ```
2. If you have many entities, the first way isn't good, Use below code for applying the global filter to all entities(**Magic way**):

   ```
   public static class ModelBuilderExtension
   {
       public static void ApplyGlobalFilters<TInterface>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Expression<Func<TInterface, bool>> expression)
       {
           var entities = modelBuilder.Model
               .GetEntityTypes()
               .Where(e => e.ClrType.GetInterface(typeof(TInterface).Name) != null)
               .Select(e => e.ClrType);
           foreach (var entity in entities)
           {
               var newParam = Expression.Parameter(entity);
               var newbody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(expression.Parameters.Single(), newParam, expression.Body);    
               modelBuilder.Entity(entity).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(newbody, newParam));
           }
       }
   }

   // Default method inside the DbContext or your default Context
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>();
       modelBuilder.Entity<Post>();

       builder.ApplyGlobalFilters<IDelete>(e => e.IsDeleted == false);
   }
   ```

And Queries will be:

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x].[BlogId], [x].[Name], [x].[Url]
    FROM [dbo].[Blog] AS [x]
    WHERE [x].[IsDeleted] = 0'
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, why when use ''t.IsCancel == Shared.Enum.CancelEnum.InActive" , query generated in sql use Cast function like  [module].[IsCancel] = CAST(0 AS tinyint)?

Comment: Thanks for the code. The error `A filter may only be applied to the root entity type 'MyBaseType'.` is possible where using multiple types per table. I fixed this by adding an attribute to those inheriting classes and added a skip to the for loop. 
`if (entity.GetCustomAttribute<SkipGlobalFilterAttribute>() != null) continue;`

Answer (score 7):

everything you suggest does not work for the following scenario: `HasQueryFilter` power, but per each HTTP request. `ApplyGlobalFilters` / `OnModelCreating` applied once for model creation. But if you reload the page with different request parameters - they won't be taken into account to filter out `DbSet`.
If you add the filter to `GetAll` call - another call '`Include`'-ing the entity won't have this filter.
We need real global mechanism to filter out `DbSet`s by specific condition - which may change per each request (page refresh).

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend the `object context`  and add an extension method that returns IQueryable

Like

```
public class CustomdbContext : DbContext
{       
    public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyCustomerFilter<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> query) where TEntity : Customer 
    {
         return query.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerctxId);
    }
}
```