# Entity Framework Core Filter DbSet

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is it possible in Entity Framework Core to automatically filter a `DbSet<TEntity>` of a `DbContext`?
I'm looking to implement [something like that](https://github.com/rjperes/DevelopmentWithADot.EntityFrameworkFilters/blob/master/DevelopmentWithADot.EntityFrameworkFilters/FilteredDbSet.cs) just for EntityFrameworkCore.
I would like to automatically filter the `IQueryable<TEntity>` before it's beeing accessed over the `DbSet<TEntity>`.

Comment: Please look at this link [Global Query Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261734/add-filter-to-all-query-entity-famework/55514664#55514664)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can look at the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#model-level-query-filters

Example

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(
            p => !p.IsDeleted
            && p.TenantId == this.TenantId );
    }
}
```

Comment: He is asking for generic DbSet<T>

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ Query Filter allows you to Filter the DbSet and support .NET Core (Make sure to read the limitation section)

Wiki: [EF+ Query Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-filter)

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.
var ctx = new EntitiesContext();

ctx.Filter<Post>(q => q.Where(x => !x.IsSoftDeleted));

// SELECT * FROM Post WHERE IsSoftDeleted = false
var list = ctx.Posts.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to implement a facade class that does the filtering:

```
public class DataService
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public DataService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<EntityType> EntityTypes => _context.EntityTypes.Where(t => t.Something == true);
}
```

Where `DataContext` is your EF DbContext, and `EntityType` is the type of your entity.

Then the other classes can just use this one. Note I did not implement `IDisposable` here, you might want to do that.

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly inside the DbContext's entities?

Comment: Odd question perhaps, but why the `EtityTypes => _context...` I mean, why not make it properties, like `public IQueryable<EntityType> EntityTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return _DataContext.EntityTypes.Where(et => et.SomeId.Equals(_someValue));
            }
        }` ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, that is exactly the same thing what I did here :) The syntax `public Type Name => _something;` is exactly the same as `public Type Name { get { return _something; }}`. It's just shorter.